# How to use asp.net web api different method in same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to use to asp.net web api different method in same api controller. I searched but I couldn't find.

For example:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    AdFindDBEntities db = new AdFindDBEntities();
    public HomeController()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Ad> AllAds()
    {
        return db.Ad.ToList();

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Ad> GetLastAds()
    {
        return db.Ad.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(20).ToList();
    }
}
```

When I run the project AllAds method running. I don't know how use to GetLastAds method. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the default route to have **{action}** in the route.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

In that way you can call multiple actions by different urls.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[Route]` attribute for separation call you actions

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/home/ads}")]
public List<Ad> AllAds()
{
 ...
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("api/home/ads/last}")]
public List<Ad> GetLastAds()
{
 ...
}
```